# How do I stub an http request globally with Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocking, twitter, testunit

How do I stub an http request, like this one to the twitter api below, on a global scope so it's valid for all tests in a Test::Unit suite?

```
stub_request(:get, "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=digiberber").
    with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Twitter Ruby Gem 1.1.2'}).
    to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

This [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) stub works within a TestCase subclass's setup() block, like

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase       
  setup do
    stub_request(...)...
  end
end
```

But doesn't get recognized if I put it within a global setup in TestCase itself:

```
require 'webmock/test_unit'
class ActiveSupport::TestCase  
  setup do
    stub_request(...)
  end
end
```

Which gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stub_request' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
```

I've also tried by patching the method def itself

```
def self.setup
  stub_request(...)
end
```

but it doesn't work either.

Something similar happens when I use [FlexMock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/) instead of WebMock. Seems to be a scope problem, but I can't figure out how to go around it. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just answered but missed that you're using Test::Unit.  Anyway, take a look at FakeWeb. https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb

Comment: wouldn't fakeweb have the same issue? register_uri() is very similar to webmock's stub_request(), and I'd need to run it globally as well

Comment: Perhaps you could abstract the HTTP request into a class or module method, which you could then easily mock or stub.

Comment: @Wizard of Ogz, actually that was my original approach - stubbing twitter gem's Twitter.user() with flexmock under global setup(). But flexmock() also doesn't get recognized :P. I think in both approaches I'm just stubbing in the wrong place, but can't figure out the correct one

Comment: ...I mean I'm just adding the stub call in the wrong place, where the mocking libs don't get recognized. I can't figure out where the correct place would be, or how to force the inclusion of those stubbing/mocking methods there. Tried FlexMock.flexmock(), for instance, just but Flexmock module just isn't there, though it's required (tried include()ing it, but no luck either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/rails-special-sauce-test-unit-setup-and-teardown/) on different ways to setup() and teardown() led me to just do

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase  
  def setup
    stub_request(...)
  end
end
```

hadn't thought of declaring it as an instance method. :P

Answer (score 2):

Using [FakeWeb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) you could do something like this:

In *test/test_helper.rb*

```
require 'fakeweb'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    # FakeWeb global setup
    FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = false # force an error if there are a net connection to other than the FakeWeb URIs
    FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, 
        "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=digiberber",
        :body => "",
        :content_type => "application/json")
  end
  def teardown
    FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = true
    FakeWeb.clean_registry # Clear all registered uris
  end
end
```

With this, you can call to the registered fakeweb from any testcase.

Answer (score 0):

The capybara driver Akephalos does support stubbing http calls. They call it filters.

http://oinopa.com/akephalos/filters.html

http://github.com/Nerian/akephalos